# Python: Why is np.where not working with two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-operator

I have the following data frame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df_test = pd.DataFrame({'id': [100, 101, 102, 103, 104], 'drive': ['4WD', None, '4WD', None, '2WD']})
>>> print(df_test)
    id drive
0  100   4WD
1  101  None
2  102   4WD
3  103  None
4  104   2WD
```

And I would like to make a new column *is_4x4*, that would be equal to 0, when *drive* is *None*, or *drive* is *2WD*. In other cases, I would like the column to be equal to 1.

I am using the following code, but the result is not as I expected:

```
>>> df_test['is_4x4'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df_test['drive']) | df_test['drive'] == '2WD', 0, 1)
>>> print(df_test)
    id drive  is_4x4
0  100   4WD       1
1  101  None       1
2  102   4WD       1
3  103  None       1
4  104   2WD       1
```

My desired output is following:

```
    id drive  is_4x4
0  100   4WD       1
1  101  None       0
2  102   4WD       1
3  103  None       0
4  104   2WD       0
```

Please, could you help me, what I am doing wrong? Why is my code not working?

Comment: Put a bracket around the second condition ... df_test['is_4x4'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df_test['drive']) | (df_test['drive'] == '2WD'), 0, 1)... that way np where knows what the test condition is

Comment: Does this work for you `np.where(np.logical_and(pd.isnull(df_test['drive']), df_test['drive'] == '2WD', 0, 1))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parentheses because priority precedence of `|` operator (bitwise OR):

```
df_test['is_4x4'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df_test['drive']) | (df_test['drive'] == '2WD'), 0, 1)
```

Or use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df_test['is_4x4'] = np.where(df_test['drive'].isna() | df_test['drive'].eq('2WD'), 0, 1)
```

---

You can check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - 6.16. Operator precedence where see `|` have higher priority as `==`:

```
Operator                                Description

lambda                                  Lambda expression
if – else                               Conditional expression
or                                      Boolean OR
and                                     Boolean AND
not x                                   Boolean NOT
in, not in, is, is not,                 Comparisons, including membership tests    
<, <=, >, >=, !=, ==                    and identity tests
|                                       Bitwise OR
^                                       Bitwise XOR
&                                       Bitwise AND

(expressions...), [expressions...],     Binding or tuple display, list display,       
{key: value...}, {expressions...}       dictionary display, set display
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution is correct and code is working. However, what does priority precedence of | operator mean?

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk - Give me some time.

Comment: @Jaroslav, just like you have an order of operations for ()^*/+- in math, all operators have an order they are applied in. Higher precedence means it gets applied first.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thank you very much for an explanation :-)