# How to correctly use dataframe.loc to call up entries containing missing data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking at the titanic dataset and I've extracted what deck a passenger's cabin was on, based on their cabin number. Most of the cabin number data was missing, so when I enter `joint_df.Deck.isnull().value_counts()` I get the following:

```
True     1137
False     379
```

Next, I want to fill in the missing data, so I have calculated a rough distribution of what deck a person's cabin  was on based on ticket class:

```
choice_dict = {
    1: [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        [.12, .22, .32, .20, .14]],
    2: [['D', 'E', 'F'], 
        [.16, .34, .50]],
    3: [['E', 'F', 'G'],
        [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]]
}
```

My thought was to iterate over the ticket classes (1st, 2nd, 3rd) with missing 'Deck' information, and fill that missing information in with `numpy.random.choice`. My attempt at that looks like this:

```
for key, value in choice_dict.items():
    pclass = key
    choices = value[0]
    probs = value[1]    
    num = len(joint_df.loc[joint_df.Pclass == key & joint_df.Deck.isnull(), 'Deck'])
    fill_in = np.random.choice(choices, size=num, p=probs)
    print("Pclass: ", pclass)
    print("num missing vals: ", num)
    print("fill ins: ", fill_in)
```

However, what I noticed is that I am only getting 72 missing values in 1st Class and 72 missing values in 3rd class, with no missing values in 2nd class.

This doesn't add up to the 1137 missing values I need to fill.

My guess is that my problem lies in the way that I am trying to use `Pandas.DataFrame.loc`...

**If so, how do I use DataFrame indexing to correctly achieve my desired results. If not, what is my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [priority operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60524789/2901002) is necessary add missing parantheses for `(joint_df.Pclass == key)`:

```
for key, value in choice_dict.items():
    pclass = key
    choices = value[0]
    probs = value[1] 
    m = (joint_df.Pclass == key) & joint_df.Deck.isnull()
    num = len(joint_df.loc[m, 'Deck'])
    #alternative
    #num = m.sum()
    fill_in = np.random.choice(choices, size=num, p=probs)
    joint_df.loc[m, 'Deck'] = fill_in
```

**Sample**:

```
import seaborn as sns

joint_df = sns.load_dataset('titanic').rename(columns = lambda x: x.capitalize())
print (joint_df.head())
   Survived  Pclass     Sex   Age  Sibsp  Parch     Fare Embarked  Class  \
0         0       3    male  22.0      1      0   7.2500        S  Third   
1         1       1  female  38.0      1      0  71.2833        C  First   
2         1       3  female  26.0      0      0   7.9250        S  Third   
3         1       1  female  35.0      1      0  53.1000        S  First   
4         0       3    male  35.0      0      0   8.0500        S  Third   

     Who  Adult_male Deck  Embark_town Alive  Alone  
0    man        True  NaN  Southampton    no  False  
1  woman       False    C    Cherbourg   yes  False  
2  woman       False  NaN  Southampton   yes   True  
3  woman       False    C  Southampton   yes  False  
4    man        True  NaN  Southampton    no   True
```

---

```
for key, value in choice_dict.items():
    pclass = key
    choices = value[0]
    probs = value[1] 
    m = (joint_df.Pclass == key) & joint_df.Deck.isnull()
    num = m.sum()
    fill_in = np.random.choice(choices, size=num, p=probs)
    joint_df.loc[m, 'Deck'] = fill_in

print (joint_df.Deck.isnull().value_counts())    
False    891
Name: Deck, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Excellent! I'd been banging my head on that one for about 4 hours. I'm going to read about priority operators and go to bed!

Comment: @rocksNwaves - Glad can help ;)